# Citadels - Can a warlord destroy a district for free?

Tags: citadels

If a district is worth one gold. Can the warlord destroy it without paying?

Answer (score 11):

Yes.

This is explicitly stated in the rules.

> 8) Warlord
>
> You receive one gold for each military (red) 
>   district in your city. At the end of your turn, you 
>   may destroy one district of your choice by paying 
>   a number of gold equal to one less than the cost 
>   of the district. Thus, **you may destroy a cost one 
>   district for free**, a cost two district for one gold, 
>   or a cost six district for five gold, etc. You may 
>   destroy one of your own districts. You may not, 
>   however, destroy a district in a city that is already 
>   completed by having eight districts (or seven 
>   districts when the Bell Tower is in play).

[Emphasis added]